# как суммировать счёт в компаниях

Tags: java

- Название компании             ,   Зарплата
- /RU/CARD2CARD ALFA_MOBILE>MOSCOW, 1500
- \RUS\MOSCOW\Ryabin\KUSCHAVEL,     300
- /RU/CARD2CARD ALFA_MOBILE>MOSCOW, 5000
- \RUS\MOSCOW\Ryabin\KUSCHAVEL,     85

там ещё много других компаний, некоторые повторяются.
я решил использовать HashSet для того, чтоб сортировать где Key(Название компании) Value(Зарплата).
У меня вопрос, как отсортировать и суммировать зарплату для каждой компании

Comment: Перебирайте в цикле, вытаскивайте название и значение. Проверяйте если есть название, то суммируйте и добавляйте зарплату, иначе добавляете название и значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

# В цикле для всех компаний
Integer currentValue = map.computeIfAbsent(companyName, k -> 0);
map.put(companyName, currentValue + companyValue);
```